# How to Open multiple Window Browser in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show my pdf in window browser, acutually it works fine for single pdf
i want to open two window browser at same time...
here is my problem...
it working any one at the same time not two......but values fetching everything working fine...Thank you in advance..

```
    if (is_chrome) {

            window.open('<%: Url.Action("PrintLabelasPDFChrome", "Shipments") %>' + '?OrderNumber=' + orderno + '&orderItemNo=' + orderItemNo + '&orderShipmentID=' + orderShipmentID + '&strPackinglistDetail=' + '' + '&shipdate=' + '' + '&OrderGuid=' + '', 'Lables', 'attribute1,attribute2');
           window.open('<%: Url.Action("PrintCustomLabel", "Shipments") %>' + '?orderShipmentID=' + orderShipmentID + '&strPackinglistDetail=CustomsDocument', 'Lables', 'attribute1,attribute2');
        }
       else {

            window.open('<%: Url.Action("PrintLabelPDF", "Shipments") %>' + '?OrderNumber=' + orderno + '&orderItemNo=' + orderItemNo + '&orderShipmentID=' + orderShipmentID + '&strPackinglistDetail=' + '' + '&shipdate=' + '' + '&OrderGuid=' + '', 'Lables', 'attribute1,attribute2');
            window.open('<%: Url.Action("PrintCustomLabel", "Shipments") %>' + '?orderShipmentID=' + orderShipmentID + '&strPackinglistDetail=CustomsDocument', 'Lables', 'attribute1,attribute2');
        }
```

Comment: Simply it should work. Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/3J7r6/

Comment: How does the above render in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is plain Javascript, not jQuery.

You simply have to specify the new windowName to create a new one. Just add a uid to the windowName, corresponding to the each pdf file.

```
window.open('actionToFileNo1', 'documentWindow1');
```

References [@MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open).